# Loop inside SELECT in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a few columns using a function F(a,b,x) from SQL Server for say 20 values. Basically it's like

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, F(a,b,1), F(a,b,2), ... F(a,b,20) 
FROM 
    table
```

Is that possible to use a loop to `SELECT F(a,b,@i)` where 0 < `@i` < 21?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to build a string dynamically and then execute it as SQL. It's not pretty though. If it's always 1-20, I would just write it out

Comment: The number is not fixed, but usually under 20. Currently I just write it out line by line which looks a bit horrible if you have to put it into another code. Anyway thanks for your kind reply!

Comment: I think you should probably rewrite the function so you don't need to do this. A SELECT statement returns a relation, which must have fixed arity (number of columns). Can you tell us what this function does?

Comment: The function itself is very simple, just query another few tables with different dates, which are obtained by DATEADD and values input here. A revised function should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "looping" in a SQL statement.  But, you can come close by doing:

```
select col1, col2, n.n, f(a, b, n.n)
from table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 . . .
      select 20
     ) n;
```

The exact syntax depends on the database you are using.  There are also ways to generate numbers, once again, depending on the database.

This generates 20 rows for each row in the table, rather than 20 columns.  The results can be pivoted if you really need them in columns.